# Does a BEAM file remember whether it was built with -Werror?

Tags: erlang, beam

I am working on a tool that deals with BEAM files, and we want to be able to assume the code was compiled with -Werror, so we don't have to repeat validations that are already done by the erl_lint compiler pass.

Is there a way to figure out if the BEAM was built with -Werror?

I'd expect `beam_lib:chunks/2` to help here, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to have what I'm looking for:

```erl
beam_lib:chunks("sample.beam", [debug_info, attributes, compile_info]).
% the stuff returned says nothing about -Werror, even if I compile with -Werror
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this information would be [always stripped](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/1baf935c0deec219544fe20f7c38a1c2a32c679d/lib/stdlib/src/erl_compile.erl#L155)

However, if you are in control of compilation process - you can put additional info into beam files, - which will be accessible through `M:module_info(compile)` and via beam chunks as well.

For example in rebar:

```
{erl_opts, [debug_info, {compile_info, [{my_key, my_value}]}]}.
```

And then:

```
1> my_module:module_info(compile).
[{version,"7.6.6"},
 {options,[debug_info, ...
 {my_key,my_value}]
```

The same is true for "discoverability" of this key directly from beam chunks:

```
2> beam_lib:chunks("my_beam.beam", [compile_info]).
{ok, ... {my_key,my_value}]}]}}
```

Meaning, that you can "stamp" your beam files with some meta-information easily. So, a workaround may be to stamp those beam files with this mark.